# An interesting question on progressions:

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

> $4.$ It is known that $\frac{1}{1^{2}} + \frac{1}{2^{2}} + \frac{1}{3^{2}}+ \ldots\text{ to }\infty = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}$.  Find the sum of the series $\frac{1}{1^{2}} + \frac{1}{3^{2}} +\frac{1}{5^{2}}+\ldots \text{ to }\infty$.

I tried thinking on it but i couldn't get an idea on how to proceed;
help please

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $S_1=\pi^2/6$ be the known series and $S_2$ the unknown series. Since the terms of $S_1$ contain all of those in $S_2$, consider what terms remain in $S_1-S_2$. Is there a common factor in all of them?

Comment: See this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268605/infinite-sum-calculation-sum-k-0-infty-frac12k12-frac34

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

for even denominators, use

$$\frac{1} {(2p)^2}=\frac {1}{4}\frac {1}{p^2}$$ for $p=1,2,3... $.

you should find
$$S_2+\frac {1}{4}S_1=S_1=\frac {\pi^2}{6} $$